# SharePoint REST returning items with incorrect values

Tags: list, rest

I'm using REST API to get all items form a list in SharePoint and this is what is happening:

Even when the item has a value in SharePoint 
[image: Values in SahrePoint List]

In the REST result I get this

[image: Values in the result]

In case you didn't notice in the image: the element values in the sharepointlist is Folder but the element value in the result of the request is Library. Why does this happens? I can't understand.

I'm doing a simple GET:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('myList')/Items",
```

Comment: I'm having problems replicating your result.  I think you're using JavaScript and are returning json, correct?

Comment: What is the column type? What is the value when you look at it in the browser and not in debugger? Has someone changed that value since you last looked at it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using JavaScript and returning json

Comment: The column type is single line of text, In the browser is the same value as in the debugger and nobody has change it, the value in the list still remain as Folder instead of Library

Comment: Try "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('myList')/Items?$filter=(Title eq 'Budget')". Do you only get back more that one item? Also, do you have content approval on?

Comment: I have two items with that name. But I've already tried with unique titles too. No I don't have content approval turned on in that site

Comment: Just a hunch, could 'element' be a reserved name? What happens with another fieldname; what happens with a Calculated Column referencing [element].

Comment: I was using another column before and the same was happening, I don't know what else to do